# How to get Total in crosstab pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like below, I want to convert this into cross table using below code,

```
g= list('M'*75)+list('F'*75)
c =list('B'*51)+list('T'*24)+list('B'*49)+list('T'*26)
df=pd.DataFrame({'Gender':g,'City':c})
tbl=pd.crosstab(df['City'],df['Gender'])
```

cross table:

```
Gender   F   M
City          
B       49  51
T       26  24
```

How to get the sum or total values of cross tab result. i.e., 49+51+26+24

So far I used this,

```
tbl.sum().sum()
```

Expected O/P:

```
150
```

Even though I got the required result, I'm wondering Do I need to use two chain `sum` functions here for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think not, you can convert DataFrame to numpy array and call [`numpy.sum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) with no axis, so it `sum` all values to scalar:

```
print (tbl.values.sum())
150

print (np.sum(tbl.values))
150
```

Comment: Thanks to the solution, May I know what are all other possible approach for this kind

Comment: @MohamedThasinah - You can play with `axis=1` like `a = tbl.sum(axis=1).sum()`, `a = tbl.sum().sum(axis=1)` but it is only more typing like yous solution `tbl.sum().sum()`. Now I have no another idea.

Comment: Above solutions are excellent, but since you wanted to know more possible solutions :) You could add parameter margins=True to pd.crosstab: tbl=pd.crosstab(df['City'],df['Gender'], margins=True) which adds row and column totals to your crosstab and then get the total with: tbl['All']['All'].